# ElementCriteriaModel combine with 'and' and 'or' filters

Tags: elementcriteriamodel, craft2

Saying I want to convert the following SQL query into ElementCriteriaModel:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE fieldA = 1 AND (fieldB = 1 or fieldC = 1)
```

I can't find a way in ElementCriteriaModel to do so.

```
{% craft.users({
    fieldA: 1,
    fieldB: 1,
    fieldC: 1, // where can we put the 'or' filter?
}) %}
```

I can do this using DbCommand, but just curious if there's anyway we can do that via ElementCriteriaModel?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're looking for [this section](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/templating/elementcriteriamodel.html#setting-the-parameters) on passing parameters to `ElementCriteriaModel`s, in the docs.

The examples fail to highlight one aspect of the query you're building, but I think you'll find the same strategies hold up for many field values, as well as basic Element properties (like `id`, `title`, etc.)

For example…

```
craft.users({ myFieldA: [1, 2, 3] }).all()
```

…will fetch `User` Elements with the custom `myFieldA` matching the values `1`, `2`, or `3`. The `or` is implicit!

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your reply. However, that's not exactly what I'm looking for. Your answer is doing an 'OR' filter on ONE field, but I'm trying to do an 'OR' on two different fields and also combine with 'AND' filter with other fields.